# What are the Greek terms for Platos terms for the Good/Beautiful

Tags: plato, parmenides

It's a little too easy in my mind to confuse Platos notion of the Good, from which the forms emanate from, of which one is the Beautiful, and the other is Justice; with other notions in ethics - ie Christian, or conventional everyday use that's it would be useful to have the Greek terms for these that Plato uses.

Also, does Plato use the term One as a synonym for the Good? And is his word for this the same as Parmenides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Greek terms are: good = agathos, beautiful = kalos, just = dikaios, the one = to hen, god = theos.

I do not remember any passage from Plato where he equates to hen = theos. I assume the apotheosis of to hen is due to later new-Platonic philosophy.

Comment: I would also doubt that Plato equated 'theos' to 'to hen'; and probably not Plotinus either; possibly with its synthesis in Christian theology.

Comment: Perhaps in Plato's Parmenides the arguments about the sole and eternal existence of the one can imply that one equals god and good (agatho).